# Generate Random Prime number in C/C++ between 2 limits

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, primes

Is there a built in function that can generate a random prime number between 2 given limits in C/C++?

I want a function that can generate a random prime number between 1 million and 1 billion

Comment: `return 19394489;` random enough?

Comment: Guaranteed random by dice roll

Comment: At dice? Whilst rolling?

Comment: Okay, seriously, what are your needs? You could generate a (pseudo) random number in that range and pick the next larger or smaller prime, depending on which end you are nearer.

Comment: a prime number over 1,000,000 and 1,000,000,000 ?

Comment: You have to decide what you mean by random. What is the distribution?

Comment: Welcome to C! The only "built in" functions are very general. There is nothing built in that is anywhere near as specific as this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this efficiently like so:

1. Generate a random number in that interval;
2. Check if it is divisible by any of the first few primes (say `2 .. 17`, experiment for best results). If yes, go to 1;
3. Use [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) to test for primality.

Also see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) for a similar, a bit more complex, idea.

Comment: I suspect that by random he means uniformly distributed within the set of prime numbers. Your solution won't be, because random numbers are not uniformly distributed. It might be close enough, though.

Comment: @Don Reba: As long as the input random numbers are uniformly distributed in the range, the primes chosen by this method will be uniformly distributed among the primes in that range, too.

Comment: There's no need to use a probabilistic test like Miller-Rabin - 1 billion is small enough for trial factorisation to be feasible.

Comment: Don't forget that it is possible that if you pick the wrong range, there are no prime numbers at all in the selected range.  Make sure that your code will exit gracefully if it doesn't find anything after enough (for some value of 'enough') tries.  Infinite loops can really slow down your program.

Answer (score 3):

When I had to do this I created a function called isPrime(). isPrime() would check and determine if a number was prime.

isPrime() had two different functions one that would run forever and print every prime number and another that would run up to a certain number.

You could populate an array with all of the prime numbers between i and j. Then generate a random number that is less than or equal to the size of the array. Use this random number to select an element from the array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Those easy-to-use `uint64_t[1000000000ull]` arrays

Comment: @chris This will be very slow .. I need a faster solution .

Comment: What you need is to put some thought into the problem! You're expecting magic.

Comment: Prem, I agree that it will be very slow. I wasn't trying to provide the worlds most efficient solution. One workaround for this would be to pre-load the data in the array and store it locally.

Answer (score 3):

To generate a random number between two bounds do this

```
extern unsigned int urand();
int lower = 1000000;
int upper = 1000000000;
int p = urand() % (upper - lower) + lower;
```

To test if a number near 1 billion is prime it is sufficient to do trial division by all primes < sqrt(1 billion) = 31622.  There are about 3400 such primes.  Make an array

```
unsigned short primes[3400] = { 2, 3, 5, .. 31657 }
```

and divide by them all.  If all trial divisions have remainder != 0 then the number is prime.

I doubt any of the more sophisticated primality tests will be faster for such small primes.

Comment: I compared trial division with primes to an optimized primality test in this range. Trial division took 53 times longer (22 microseconds vs. 0.4 microseconds). It may be good enough, but in this range there's serious benefit to a faster test, since otherwise you need thousands of divisions.